# C#: Integration Add-in for Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am creating a appointment checker on outlook shared calendars by picking up the profiles from a inifile. It picks the first shared calendar but when it loops to the second, it gives me a null reference exception error. Can you advice what I am doing wrong.

Should the outlook recip be a list? Would appreciate some help

```
string CalendarName = iniFile.GetValue("Appointmentdays", "Calendarname");
List<string> names = CalendarName.Split(',').Reverse().ToList();

foreach (var name in names)
        //for (var i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            //Create Recipient

            Outlook.Recipient recip =  oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(name);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            String oCalendarName = CalendarFolder.Name;
            String oCalendarEntryID = CalendarFolder.EntryID;
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, which lines gives you the error?

Comment: Outlook.Recipient recip =  oApp.Session.CreateRecipient(name);

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, The above line gives me an error. I think my question is more, how to loop through the outlook recipients

Comment: That means oApp.Session is null. After crating oApp, retrieve the Namespace object from oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"), then call Namespacee.Logon instead of using oApp.Session.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for helping me out. I have added an image of the issue that I am having in my code to the question. The problem for me is that I am able to loop through the first name perfectly fine, when it tries to loop through the second names and there after it gives me the error.

Comment: I see that you are the expert. Wonderful tools you've made..I will give them a try :). I am trying to find your email to connect with you but cant find it. Just to explain more about what I am developing.